# libpcap и debian 8.1

Tags: linux, c, libpcap

В программе использую библиотеку **libpcap** для перехвата пакетов с карточки, которая не имеет IP адреса (на этот порт пакеты отправляет маршрутизатор).

Одинаковый код и на ***debian 7 (ядро 3.2.0-4-amd64)***, и на ***ubuntu 14.04 (ядро 3.13.0-24-generic)*** и на ***debian 8.1 (ядро 3.16.0)***.

При этом на ***debian 7*** и на ***ubuntu 12.04 (ядро 3.11.0-19-generic)*** при помощи функции **pcap_next_ex()** я могу получить пакет, а на ***ubuntu 14.04*** и ***debian 8.1*** не могу.

В чем могут быть проблемы?

[code](https://ideone.com/c6JlbU)

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void intranet_packages(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);

int main() {

    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]; 
    char *dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_live(dev, 1600, 1, -1, errbuf);
    const unsigned char *packet;

    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("1 fasfas %s\n", errbuf);
        return -1;
    }

    char filter[] = "";
    struct bpf_program fp;
    memset((void*)&fp, 0, sizeof(struct bpf_program));

    int result = pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter, 0, 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf("2 fasfas\n");
        return -1;
    }

    result = pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp);
    if (result < 0) {
        printf("3 fasfas\n");
        return -1;
    }

    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    int i;
    while (1) {

        packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
        printf("%d ", header.len);
        if (result < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    pcap_close(handle);
}
```

*P.S.* *wireshark* и *tcpdump* используя эту же библиотеку почему-то получают пакеты, а с  помощью этого кода, как написано выше, на debian 8.1 и ubuntu 14.04 я не могу получить пакеты.

Comment: Ваш вопрос выглядит как-то так: «Я делаю что-то, и это не всегда работает. Что я делаю не так?»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с libpcap 1.5  ядра версии ~3.2 появился TPACKET_V3.

Подробнее и "лекарство" здесь:
https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/354#issuecomment-42146519 .

Т.е. заменить

```
pcap_t *handle = pcap_open_live(dev, 1600, 1, -1, errbuf);
```

на

```
pcap_t *handle = pcap_create(dev, errbuf);
if(!handle){
    printf("1 fasfas %s\n", errbuf);
    return -1;
}
pcap_set_promisc(handle, 1);
pcap_set_snaplen(handle, 1600);
pcap_set_immediate_mode(handle, 1);
pcap_activate(handle);
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `pcap_set_immediate_mode(handle, 1)` заменяет `timeout`. 
Проверено мной на **debian-8.5** , **libpcap-1.7.4** .

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.